# Wiki page scraping using Sheets (why is query not always working right?)

Tags: regex, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, wikipedia-api

so with the help of the ppl here I've got this query for scraping a certain section from wiki page, but I've noticed it's not always working right. In some cases, it's scraping other data points sections in the page, and I can't figure out why.
I only wanna get the 'date of death' section (if the page has one), but in some cases it returns smth else.

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTXML("https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/"&A2, "//*"), 
 "select Col2 where Col1 = 'date of death' and Col2 is not null"),FALSE)
```

Is there a way I can improve the formula/query to increase its accuracy? Also, is there a way to make it work faster (on my main sheet when I apply it to loads of data it's taking very long to update).
Here's the sample [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V-YdEPvIi8s-ryonwe_eKS0dheCQqu2Ff0GGRLjLLfo/edit#gid=0). Thanks

Comment: Give this a try `=IFERROR(VALUE(IMPORTXML("https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/"&A5, "//*[@data-property-id='P570']//*[@class='wikibase-snakview-body']/*[contains(@class,'wikibase-snakview-value')]")),FALSE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/"&A7, "//*"), 1000, 2), 
 "select Col2 
  where Col1 matches 'date of death' 
    and Col2 is not null", 0), "\s(.*)\s\d.*reference.*"), FALSE)
```

[image]